# Insert a String inside an Array

Tags: php, arrays, string

How can I include an string in an array?

**emailconfig.php**

```
$globalemail 'info@site.com'=>'site'";
```

I want to make a new array like this:

**sendemail.php**

```
include "emailconfig.php"
$fulllist=array('info@forum.com'=>'forum', '$globalemail');
// the Array MUST must appear above, ideally it would look like this
// $fulllist=array('info@forum.com'=>'forum', 'info@site.com'=>'site');
```

It brings PHP error because of the =>

Comment: So `$globalemail` contains the string `"info@site.com'=>'site'"`? (p.s. it's missing a `'` before `info`)

Comment: -scratches head- This makes no sense at all. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: It's amazing how debilitating a failure to use the correct terminology can be to the communication process.

Comment: sorry guys, I updated my code, it cannot be anything else, the final line needs to be like that fulllist in the comments. Can't use trim etc

Comment: `$globalemail 'info@site.com'=>'site'";` is not valid PHP.  What exactly does `emailconfig.php` contain?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: What do you mean by "Can't use trim"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is: in your `emailconfig.php`, you should have 2 variables, `$globalemailkey` and `$globalemailvalue`.

```
$globalemailkey = 'info@site.com';
$globalemailvalue = 'site';

$fulllist = array('info@forum.com'=>'forum', $globalemailkey => $globalemailvalue);
```

Or, store an array in `emailconfig.php`, and use `array_merge`.

```
$globalemail = array('info@site.com' => 'site');

$fulllist = array('info@forum.com'=>'forum');
$fulllist = array_merge($fulllist, $globalemail);
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for this. I really love learning in PHP. I really enjoy it. What a great language. Beats Java any day.

Comment: PHP is fun :-)  Glad I could help, happy coding :-D

Answer (score 2):

```
$fulllist=array('info@forum.com'=>'forum');
$globalemail = "info@site.com'=>'site'";
$parts = explode('=>', $globalemail);
$fulllist[trim($parts[0], "'")] = trim($parts[1], "'");
```

http://ideone.com/mmvu9

Comment: It has to look like the comment in my code. Sorry, I updated it just now.. apologies

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: yes, and it does look like you want. Check the ideone link

Comment: "repped" for the efforts. Went with the simple solution below.

Answer (score 2):

You *could*  **But You Shouldn't** use `eval` to do something like `eval("array($yourstring)");`. But you shouldn't. really. please.

You can do all sorts of things like `preg-match` or `explode`, but couldn't you easier find the source of those pieces of information, and work from there?

Comment: This seems to be an opinion? Thanks for the comments though! I went with Rocket solution!

Comment: Although it is an opinion, eval is widely frowned upon and I personally believe him to be right in saying that you shouldn't use it.

Comment: There are many drawbacks to using it. You can call it an opinion, but that doesn't change those drawbacks. To "back up" my claims, head over to the official documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php and check out the big yellow "caution" block, with the bold&italic notice `Its use thus is discouraged.`.